# How to connect to Oracle database with multiple-address-line TNS in Pentaho Data Integration/Kettle ETL

Tags: database, oracle, pentaho, kettle, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to connect to an Oracle databse with PDI. I've successfully connect to the database with  Oracle SQL Developer and sqlplus using TNS. The connection string I used in sqlplus is just something like username/password@tnsname.

I followed the steps [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63118684/how-to-connect-pentaho-data-integration-with-oracle-and-tns) to connect to the same database in PDI, but got the error "ORA-12504:TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA".

The item in my tnsnames.ora looks something like this:

```
sample_TNS.world=
(DESCRIPTION=
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(FAILOVER=on)
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1.com)(PORT=38000))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2.com)(PORT=38000))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host3.com)(PORT=38000)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=TEST.COM)))
```

Unlike most examples, it has got multiple ADDRESSes, so I just picked one of the HOSTS to fill into the "Host Name" field in PDI and copied the entire thing following the equals sign into the "Database Name" field. I also tried to not include every (ADDRESS=xxx) in the "Database Name" field, but only the one I used in the "Host Name" field (everything else was kept intact).

I've googled the error and [some](https://debug.to/2312/ssrs-ora-12504-tns-listener-was-not-given-the-servicename-in-connectdata) suggests it could be that the (Description=xxxx) string not correctly formed. However, I've check it multiple times that I'm pasting it correctly, no typoes and the brackets do match (and I was able to make the connection with SQL developer and sqlplus so the TNS string should be correctly formed).

I've also made a simple Oracle database on the local machine and successfully connected to it with PDI (not using TNS names of course), so I don't think it's the problem with the drivers.

Some other methods I've tried including using "Generic database" as connection type instead of "Oracle" as mentioned [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/50913-How-to-fill-in-speical-JDBC-connection-string/) (but I failed to get my head around the 2nd and 3rd method mentioned by shassan2) as well as leaving host and port blank and filling the DatabaseName with the service description as mentioned [here](https://forums.pentaho.com/threads/90924-Adding-oracle-datasource-with-a-service-name-as-opposed-to-a-sid-giving-error/). I tried to adjust things here and there but just kept getting all kinds of error, including the same ORA-12504,TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor, No suitable driver found, IO Error: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection, etc (too many that I've lost my count of the errors). The links in those "aged" forum posts are all down at the moment, so it will be extremely  helpful if anyone can show me the right way to make the connection.
I'm using 64-bit Windows, Pentaho Community Edition 9.3.0.0-428

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_352"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_352-b08)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.352-b08, mixed mode)
```

and put the driver ojdbc8.jar under

```
data-integration/lib/
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

UPDATE-I tried Wireshark and that's what I got:

Attempt 1: leave host and port empty, and put that DESCRIPTION bulk in the Database Name field, as suggested by Ana GH

```
"3DU<zE2Í%@M
¬Gô
Rípÿ[TNrÞPì
(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.xx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=38000)))(CONNECT_DATA=(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=myusername))(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=TEST.COM)(CONNECTION_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxx)))
```

Attempt 2: Picked one of the HOSTS to fill into the "Host Name" field and copied the entire thing following the equals sign into the "Database Name" field as suggested in the first link in this question body.

```
"3DU<zEöÍ·@K»
¬Gô
Ró»pùO0çÜP…@Î(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=(DESCRIPTION=(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(FAILOVER=on)(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1.com)(PORT=38000)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=TEST.COM))))(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=myusername))(CONNECTION_ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx))(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.xx.xxx.xxx)(PORT=38000)))
```

I've checked that the HOST (both domain and ip form) is correct and the HOST do match with what I got from tnsnames.ora.

Comment: There should be a line (or lines) in the listener log file on the database server that shows the incoming connection request with the basic TNS parameters submitted by the client, along with the "12504" error code. That will help you understand what is actually coming through and how it may have been misconfigured or corrupted. What does that log entry show?

Comment: @pmdba Thank you for the advice. I'm afraid I don't have access to the database server, but I'll see if I can get some help and I'll let you know once I get the log.

Comment: @pmdba Still, it's highly unlikely that I'll be able to see the log. Do you have any advice in that case? Maybe ways to see what Pentaho's sending out?

Comment: In the absence of logs, you will probably need a packet capture tool like Wireshark: https://www.wireshark.org/

Comment: @pmdba I've updated the question body with the content captured with Wireshark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you let me know the Oracle JDBC driver version that you are using?
Based on the JDBC version, you can pass the TNS Alias as part of the connection string. Check out the [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/developers/post/four-facets-of-database-connectivity-for-java-applications#TNS) for more details.

Comment: Thank you for this link, it worked! I tried tons of ways to form my connection string, and this is how I get it to work in pentaho. I chose 'Generic database' for Connection Type, 'Native(JDBC)' for Access, 'Oracle' or 'Generic Database' both work for Dialect field, "jdbc:oracle:thin:@sample_TNS.world" for connection URL, "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" for driver class Name. I got my driver ojdbc8.jar [here](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html)

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you have a RAC (Real Application Cluster) Oracle Database, the administrator should have set up a SCAN (*I can't find what is the letter soup to produce that name*) to connect without needing to specify all the hosts, so you can have something like this to connect in your TNSNAMES.ORA:

```
SCAN_TNS=
(DESCRIPTION=
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=SCAN_NAME)(PORT=port_for_scan))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SCAN_SERVICE_NAME)))
```

And in PDI you can use an JDBC connection type, with an Oracle database type selected, and you fill up the host (SCAN_NAME), port (port_for_scan), and in Database name (SCAN_SERVICE_NAME, or sometimes depending on how is configured, I have needed to use /SCAN_SERVICE_NAME).

However, if you don't have the SCAN information or it hasn't been set up, you can leave host and port empty, and put this in the Database Name field:

```
(DESCRIPTION=
(CONNECT_TIMEOUT=5)(TRANSPORT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3)(RETRY_COUNT=3)(ADDRESS_LIST=(LOAD_BALANCE=off)(FAILOVER=on)
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host1.com)(PORT=38000))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host2.com)(PORT=38000))
(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=host3.com)(PORT=38000)))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=TEST.COM)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice. Unfortunately, I got ORA-12504,TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor when I leave host and port empty, and put that DESCRIPTION bulk in the Database Name field :( I've retried with Oracle SQL Developer to make sure the database server is functioning properly.

Comment: I've updated the question body with the content captured with Wireshark with this method. Please don't hesitate to tell me if you spot anything unusual.